# Python Beautifulsoup not finding text of HTML data

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to make a web request that gets data from a specific website and prints it out on the console.
For that I'm using Beautifulsoup and requests. You can see the HTML Data from the website below but I'm not getting the output of the 2 coordinates that you can see below. I don't know if it is important to mention, that the 2 coordinates on the webiste are constantly changing. Thanks for helping me!

HTML:

```
<div class="cockpitItem">
     <h3>Bodenpunkt</h3>
   <p id="gpt">
    "42,67° Nord" #Coordinate 1 that I want to get
    <br>
    "170,38° Ost" #Coordinate 2 that I want to get
  </p>
</div>
```

Python Code:

```
url = "https://www.astroviewer.net/iss/de/"
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")

body = soup.find("p",{"id": "gpt"})

print(f"HTML: {body}")
print(f"Text: {body.text}")
```

Output:

```
HTML: <p id="gpt"> <br/> </p> #It finds the right part of the HTML data
Text:
```

Comment: I think the problem is that the page is constantly updating, and I don't think BeatifulSoup is suited for that.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is polling for that data from https://www.astroviewer.net/iss/ws/orbit.php. As specified in this file: https://www.astroviewer.net/iss/javascript/orbit2.js. See `function requestOrbitData()`. It returns json you can parse.

I would have expected there to be an API which provided this data for you. You could also set-up something to poll for the data but perhaps less frequently.

Answer (score 0):

your code is ok and should work.
Ran your snippet on my machine and found out  comes back empty, that's why you're not seeing anything.

if you want to view the request use:

```
print(soup.prettify())
```

check your GET request.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine for the given html. Are you sure you're getting to the right parts of the html? See below for reproducible example. Also, as long as the html structure of the page doesn't change, it doesn't matter if the coordinates change.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_text = '''
<div class="cockpitItem">
     <h3>Bodenpunkt</h3>
   <p id="gpt">
    "42,67° Nord"
    <br>
    "170,38° Ost"
  </p>
</div>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, 'html.parser')
body = soup.find('p', {'id': 'gpt'})
print(f"Text: {body.text.strip()}")
```

Output:

```
Text: "42,67° Nord"

    "170,38° Ost"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because the default value of the "gpt div" is empty, and his content is updated by javascript.

Unfortunately, you can't use the **requests** library in this case, you have to use a library that contains a navigator like, I most known one is **Selenium**.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily simulate what's on that web-page with a simple call to an API.

Here's how:

```py
from datetime import datetime
import time

import requests

while True:
    iss_position = requests.get(
        "http://api.open-notify.org/iss-now.json",
    ).json()["iss_position"]
    output = [
        round(float(iss_position['latitude']), 2),
        round(float(iss_position['longitude']), 2),
        datetime.utcnow().time().strftime('%H:%M:%S'),
    ]
    print("{:>5}° Nord {:>5}° Ost {:>5} UTC".format(*output))
    time.sleep(1)
```

Sample output:

```
49.58° Nord 167.23° Ost 14:42:54 UTC
49.61° Nord 167.37° Ost 14:42:56 UTC
49.63° Nord 167.51° Ost 14:42:57 UTC
49.66° Nord 167.64° Ost 14:42:59 UTC
49.69° Nord 167.78° Ost 14:43:00 UTC
49.72° Nord 167.92° Ost 14:43:02 UTC
```